# LuaJIT or eLua for embedded systems?

Tags: lua

I think LuaJIT is just awesome, and now I see eLua as well.

I am just curious as to when an embedded programmer would choose one over the other for embedded systems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "embedded systems." Do you mean "mobile applications" or  "put it into a microwave?"

eLua is for the *latter*. It is for writing code for specific hardware devices at a fairly low level, but still using Lua. You shouldn't necessarily use it for anything else.

LuaJIT is not specifically for any particular kind of embedded programming. Indeed, the only reason LuaJIT is popular for ARM devices is that its JIT/interpreter recognizes the difference between floating-point numbers and integers (many ARM chips tend to have lousy floating-point performance). The standard Lua interpreter doesn't offer that, because it was designed for systems where floating-point operations were reasonably fast.

Answer (score 0):

Luajit is not the same as Lua and eLua. These are quite slow interpreters in comparison to Luajit - so Luajit on embedded would be much more ideal.

http://luajit.org/performance_arm.html
Additionally using the ffi you can call other modules functions within Lua. Luajit is also bytecode compliant with Lua 5.1.4